# Grab Everything in

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I am trying to get the store names and addresses from an HTML output that I got. However, it's telling me that my delimiters are incorrect. Any kind of help I can get on this is greatly appreciated!

I just need help to pull out everything in between `<strong>` and `</td>`

Source code:

```
<td>
    <p><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="google.maps.event.trigger($('#map').data('gomarker1'), 'click');"><strong>KMART 7418</strong></a></p>
    4330 CAMINO DE LA PLZ<br />
    SAN YSIDRO, CA. 92173
</td>
```

I have tried the following to just pull out `KMART 7418` and the address, but it's not working:

```
preg_match_all("/\<a href\=\"javascript:void(0);\"(.*?)\</td>/", $output, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $val) {
    echo $val;
}
```

Comment: whether all the stores have common prefix "KMART" ?

Comment: no, some are walmart, and seven elevens...

Comment: "it's telling me that my demlimeters are incorrect" - show the code where the `$output` variable is defined(filled with content)

Comment: `$output` shows a few of my `<td>
    <p><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="google.maps.event.trigger($('#map').data('gomarker1'), 'click');"><strong>KMART 7418</strong></a></p>
    4330 CAMINO DE LA PLZ<br />
    SAN YSIDRO, CA. 92173
</td>`

Comment: you can't assign the above string into a variable - it has conflicting quotes. You should separate the content into a few parts or to replace double quotes with single ones

Comment: I just need help to pull out everything in between `<strong>` and `<\td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is a conflict of " and ' I can't give you a working and running example. But I will show you how to do it.

```
$pos = strpos($string,"<strong>");
$pos2 = strpos($string, "</td>");
$newstring = strip_tags(substr($string, $pos, ($pos2-$pos)));
Echo $newstring; //this should be the stuff between strong and td
```

I have not tested it but it should work

EDIT: Forgot the end of string /$pos2

EDIT2:
Working example on sandbox:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/117f50cd48bf72bba0e612b6743cb8fe1b8c58a0